# PowerBI error popup with code 0xC0000005. Microsoft ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, odbc

I have been running into this error from time to time when loading a unified table that is a merged table between bigquery table and another table from another database.

**Error Message:**
*Unexpected error: Container exited unexpectedly with code 0xC0000005. PID: XXXXX.
Used features: Odbc.DataSource/Microsoft ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery/2.4.5.1014/BigQuery/2.*

Been searching but could not find a solution to this. please helppp